# como puedo imprimir todos 2 valores de un diccionario almacenados en una lista en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

si tengo por ejemplo el codigo

```
personas = [
    {"id": 1, "telefono": "2343556546", "nombre": "JUAN Anza"},
    {"id": 2, "telefono": "123454546", "nombre": "Felipe Hoyos"},
    {"id": 3, "telefono": "35465578", "nombre": "CARLOS santander"},
    {"id": 4, "telefono": "12423545", "nombre": "Luis Martinez "},
    {"id": 5, "telefono": "567667878", "nombre": "Ignacio Lopez"},
    {"id": 6, "telefono": "546657678", "nombre": "Rodrigo salinas"}
]
```

como puedo imprimir el telefono y su nombre correspondiente? y si es posible como lo puedo ordenarlos por el nombre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La función `sorted()` te permite ordenar una lista con cualquier criterio que le especifiques a través de una función que le pases en el parámetro `key`.

En este caso la función simplemente accedería al campo "nombre", por lo que se puede implementar con una `lambda` que reciba un diccionario `d` y devuelva `d["nombre"]`, así:

```
sorted(personas, key=lambda d: d["nombre"])
```

El caso de querer ordenar por un campo del diccionario es tan común, que Python te da una función ya hecha para ello en el módulo `operator`:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(personas, key=itemgetter("nombre"))
```

El resultado de `sorted` es tu lista ordenada alfabéticamente según el contenido del campo `nombre`. Ahora basta iterar por esa versión ordenada y para cada item sacar la info que te interese:

```
for d in sorted(personas, key=itemgetter("nombre")):
  print(d["nombre"], d["telefono"])
```

produce:

```
CARLOS santander 35465578
Felipe Hoyos 123454546
Ignacio Lopez 567667878
JUAN Anza 2343556546
Luis Martinez  12423545
Rodrigo salinas 546657678
```